# What is the point of creating a derivative class that is empty?

Tags: c++, subclass

I was perusing the (MSVC++ 2010) `limits` header for knowledge purposes and noticed this little gem:

```
template<class _Ty>
    class numeric_limits
        : public _Num_base
    {
        //...Insert min, max, lowest, epsilon,
        //round_error, denorm_min, infinity, quiet_Nan, and signaling_Nan
        //that return _Ty(0).
        //In other words, this class does "nothing" in a "safe" manner.*
    };
```

Followed promptly by:

```
template<class _Ty>
    class numeric_limits<const _Ty>
        : public numeric_limits<_Ty>
    {   // numeric limits for const types
    };

template<class _Ty>
    class numeric_limits<volatile _Ty>
        : public numeric_limits<_Ty>
    {   // numeric limits for volatile types
    };

template<class _Ty>
    class numeric_limits<const volatile _Ty>
        : public numeric_limits<_Ty>
    {   // numeric limits for const volatile types
    };
```

---

What purpose does an empty class provide? Why write it? I understand the purpose *in this case with templates* because of template specialization and the possibility of a constant, volatile, or constant-volatile non-fundamental type being passed in; however, in the case of non-template usage, what purpose does it provide?

---

*"nothing" and "safe" are subjective terms in this case and their layman definitions are to be applied only if the reader knows without a doubt that they truly do nothing and are safe. I do not, hence the disclaimer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The standard requires that `numeric_limits<const int>` returns the same results as `numeric_limits<int>`. The standard library authors could either duplicate all the implementation, or define one in terms of the other.

> What purpose does an empty class provide? Why write it?

It's not an empty class, it has all the same members as its base class. This is known as [implementation inheritance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inheritance_(object-oriented_programming)).

There are good reasons to define empty types, e.g. for [tag dispatching](http://www.boost.org/community/generic_programming.html#tag_dispatching) but that is not relevant here, because those `numeric_limits` partial specializations don't make empty classes anyway.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure there's a question to answer, here.  In your question, you already state that you understand why it was done *in this case*.  It sounds like you're asking us to explain why it would be done in some other hypothetical case which doesn't actually exist.

In order to know why an empty class might be useful for some other case, we'd need a real example where an empty class was used, I think.